# Huawei startResolutionForResult needs an update

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I have a huawei app with IAP so there is a code snippet

```
        if (status.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                status.startResolutionForResult(activity,REQ_CODE_BUY)
            } catch (exp: SendIntentException) {
                Log.e(TAG,exp.message!!)
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "intent is null")
        }
```

With

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_BUY) {
```

And since `onActivityResult` is deprecated i need to know how can i replace it